# Recent Samsung Internet browser update is blocking cookies for "log in" and "add to basket" on my site

Tags: browsers, cookie, session, bugs

Over the last couple of days I've had half a dozen users report to me that Samsung Internet has broken my website.  (Although of course none of them realise this, they think the site is broken).  Essentially it's blocking session cookies I believe.  Can't log in, can't add an item to the basket.  Quite important things!

The default settings of the browser when I test it are:

```
Settings > Sites and downloads > Site permissions > Cookies > Allow all cookies
Privacy > Smart anti-tracking > Always
```

If I turn the smart anti-tracking off, the site works again.  It claims that the only thing it's found and blocked is Google Analytics... But site broken with it on, site working with it off.

Anyone have further insight or advice of how to deal with this?

**Edit** for now I've resorted to an ugly message upon sniffing the UA string, advising people to use a different browser.  ☹

Comment: I had never heard of this browser before, but I'm not sure how I missed it. According to [this](https://backlinko.com/browser-market-share#samsung-internet-market-share) it has been 3% of the global browser market since 2017.

Comment: The smart anti-tracking feature described [here](https://browserhow.com/how-to-enable-privacy-settings-on-samsung-internet/) as "Automatically remove tracking cookies to prevent websites from seeing where you go on the web" is worded like it would prevent 3rd-party cookies that track usage across many sites.  Are your "log in" and "add to cart" functionality implemented with first-party cookies?

Comment: Yep, and I'm certainly not up to anything dodgy.  Just using boggo PHP sessions to remember login & cart.  It shows me what it's blocked when I visit my site, and all it shows as being blocked is google analytics.

Comment: "advising people to use a different browser." - Or to disable "Smart anti-tracking"? Presumably this can be disabled on a site-by-site basis?

Comment: I wanted to sway away from suggesting they disable Smart anti-tracking, because it makes it sound like my site is up to no good.... and it's not.

Comment: This issue has gone away now, without me changing anything, and without my installation of Samsung Internet changing.  My phone DID do an OS update 9 days ago, maybe that fixed it.  Or maybe the app phones home to Samsung and something changed at their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart Anti Tracking has to be disabled on my Samsung galaxy s10e to make Samsung Internet usable for some standard websites such as BBC. Completely unusable otherwise. I'm surprised there's not more fuss about it.

Comment: If you look it up on the Play store, and view reviews, and sort by most recent, there's plenty of people griping there.  But I've seen no mention of the issue on various webdev forums/subreddits etc.  ‍♂️

Comment: "or Chrome" - Is "Smart Anti Tracking" a phone feature, not just a browser feature?!

Comment: Regarding Chrome, my mistake, Smart Anti Tracking is browser specific, not phone. The problem isn't there with Chrome.

Comment: This issue has gone away now, without me changing anything, and without my installation of Samsung Internet changing.  My phone DID do an OS update 9 days ago, maybe that fixed it.  Or maybe the app phones home to Samsung and something changed at their end.